# How to mock qraphQL/Apollo query response for testing action-creator in redux?

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, graphql, jestjs

As I didn't have much experience with graphQL/Apollo, mocking query response for testing with Jest got me confused. 
I have the following action creator:

```js
export const fetchSomething = _id => (dispatch) => {
  client.query({
    query: gql`
    {
      something(_id: "${_id}") {
        _id
        somedata
      }
    }`,
  })
    .then(something => dispatch({
      type: FETCH_SOMETHING,
      payload: something.data,
    }));
};
```

And the following test which doesn't work

```js
  describe('fetchSomething', () => {
    it('should dispatch correct type and data correctly', async () => {
      const dispatch = jest.fn();
      client.query =
        async () => new Promise(resolve => resolve({ something: 'something' }));
      await fetchSomething('xxx')(dispatch);
      expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: FETCH_SOMETHING,   payload: {something: 'something');
    });
  });
```

ApolloClient.js file of mine

```js
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost/lib/index.umd';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql',
});

export default client;
```

Usually, for methods like `fetch`, it is enough to resolve promise to mock the response. Which doesn't work for graphql/apollo for me now. How can I mock the response in this case?

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, have you checked Apollo mocking documentation? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/mocking.html

Comment: Yes, it is not client side mocking

Comment: Hi, check this answer that can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/53586472/8157186

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues:

1 - You aren't returning the `client.query` promise, so `await fetchSomething` in the test isn't actually waiting for that promise to return before moving on to the `expect`. `return client.query` should fix that.

2 - You might also need to inject the client into the action creator. `redux-thunk` has a `withExtraArgument` option that lets you do just that. When you create your redux store and apply middleware, you can pass in the actual Apollo client, and then in your tests you can pass in your `client` with the mocked `query`:

```
await fetchSomething('xxx')(dispatch, _, client); // the 2nd argument (getState) is unused
```

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: tnx, will try it out