# Changing data for route in cypress test for QraphQL endpoint

Tags: javascript, testing, graphql, integration-testing, cypress

I have an Angular application using QraphQL.
I write a test in cypress, looking like this:

```
it('should do something', () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route('POST', '/graphql', 'fixture:data1.json');
  // data is loaded from the endpoint to populate the page
  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/#/something/somethingElse');

  // when the button is clicked, the same endpoint is called again,
  // but now I need it to deliver some other data.
  cy.get('button')
    .click();
});
```

Can anyone provide me with a way to set this up?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use [easygraphql](https://easygraphql.com/) to solve this challenge!! There are multiple packages that can be used:

1. [easygraphql-now](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-now/overview): you can create a script on your `package.json` that will run `"easygraphql-now schema.gql --graphiql --local -p=7000"` where you pass the schema route, local and graphiql flag, and the port... so when you run it; it will create a mocked server of the passed schema, so your Angular application will make request to a server that will respond a mock of your query. Here is a [post](https://medium.com/@estrada9166/how-i-mocked-my-schema-for-my-cypress-tests-c34b380fe20c) that can be useful.
2. [easygraphql-mock](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-mock/overview): if you want to return a complete mock of the type, you can use this package, and with this, you don't have to create fixtures for each type.
3. [easygraphql-tester](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-tester/overview): It's similar to [easygraphql-mock](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-mock/overview) but with the difference that you can return the mock of the query, check the [docs](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-tester/usage#mocking-queries-and-mutations)

If you decide to use [easygraphql](https://easygraphql.com/) to solve this, feel free to create the example on the repo, there is an issue [here](https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-tester/issues/33) to create an example using Cypress